# Calculate mean for every 4 columns, starting from a specific column in dataframe and output each mean result to np array for further processing

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

Need your assistance here on how to calculate the mean for every 4 columns for each row and output the mean to a numpy array.

```
df = pd.read_excel (open(excel_path,'rb'), skiprows= 5, skipfooter= 27)
```

I am using pandas readexcel to import the excel data in the dataframe which looks like the below:

```
   Variable  2003 4Q          2004 1Q   2004 2Q     2004 3Q    2004 4Q  ....... 2020 1Q
0  A         unwanted_value1  913614    921129      924066     942764     
1  B         unwanted_value2  49757     51065.7     52029.2    51213.1     
2  C         unwanted_value3  19255.4   19152.5     18857      16825     
3  D         unwanted_value4  na        na          na         na    
4  E         unwanted_value5  25092.1   26505.2     27760      28604.6   
5  F         unwanted_value6  863857    870063      872037     891551
```

As you can see, there are 2 issues:

1. Some parts of the data are incomplete (for example, 2003 only has result for quarter 4) and I need to exclude them.
2. There are "na" values in certain row.

I have difficulty trying to combine .mean and .iloc

df.mean(axis=0, skipna=True, level=None, numeric_only=None)

I tried using a counter to keep track of every 4 result and column_index to indicate the column to start the calculation.

For example, I assign value 3 to column_index which I think will let the calculation start from 2004 1Q and then feed df.iloc[column_index] to a df.mean method. However, I got a bit confused as to how I can combine them together.

Also, the method has to account for a way to stop at specific column index.

```
counter = 0 # counts every 4 result and reset again.
column_index = 3

while True:

    if counter != 4:

           #code need to calculate the average of the quarterly result using column index and output to numpy array.
          column_index += 4
           counter += counter

    elif counter == 4:
         counter = 0
        
return()
```

Desired numpy array which will be used for further processing:

```
[average_for_2004  average_for_2005 average_for_2006 average_for_2007 .....]
```

Please browse to the end of the site and click on "Singapore External Debt Statistics, (End Of Period), Quarterly " link to get to the site for excel file export (need to select export as .xlsx and pop-up blocker temporarily disabled for download dialog box to appear):
https://www.singstat.gov.sg/find-data/search-by-theme/economy/external-debt/latest-data

Comment: You only need the mean per row for those 4 quarters or for the whole year across all rows?

Comment: Hi Andreas, I need the mean for the 4 quarters for each year till 2019.

Comment: But your desired output shows average per year not per quarter.

Comment: Hi Andreas, sorry I kinda misinterpret your question.  The average in my desired output for example for 2004, is the average number for the 4 quarters.  For example, Q1: 1000, Q2:2000, Q3:1000 and Q4: 2000, so the expected value for average_for_2004 would be 1500. Hope that adds a bit of clarity.

Comment: ok, have you tried the code in my answer? Should work then as you want.

Comment: Hi Andreas, my output is a {}. I have included a link to the website to get the .xlsx file for testing. I think the program stopped at the .split("_")  and or condition for the header. Thus, it couldn't move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
valid_years = [y.split("_")[0] for y in df.columns if y.endswith("_Q1") | y.endswith("_Q2") | y.endswith("_Q3") | y.endswith("_Q4")]
valid_years = [x for x in set(valid_years) if valid_years.count(x)==4]

results = {}
for year in valid_years:
    results[year] = df.filter(regex='^'+str(year), axis=1).unstack().astype(float).mean(skipna=True)

print(results)
```

Comment: @user14074078 I don't unerstand your comment.

Comment: Hi Andreas,  can I seek some clarification for your codes? For the 1st line, y.split"_"[0], I am guessing that you are telling the program to split the data using the delimiter "_" for all the columns if it ends with the suffix "_Q1", "_Q2", "_Q3" or "_Q4" but how would the machine interpret the part on the [0]. The 2nd line seems to be a counter for every 4 counts.

Comment: line 1: get a list of all columns, split it at "_" if it ends on a quarter take the first part bof the splitted string (at index 0). Just exectute the first line and print(valid_years). Line 2: after we have a list with valid years, return only those years which have 4 entries in the list. Now you have a list of all years which occured in the columns 4x.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you for your assistance in this! Really appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First separate the columns to be aggregated (all columns starting from *2004 1Q*):

```
df2 = df.loc[:, '2004 1Q':]
```

Then generate the grouping dictionary:

```
grpDct = { t: t.split(' ')[0] for t in df2.columns }
```

It will map ranges of consecutive 4 columns to groups.

And the actual computation includes:

- group (horizontally) by the above dictionary,
- compute means for each group,
- join the first column of *df* with the above grouping.

The code to do it is:

```
result = df[['Variable']].join(df2.groupby(grpDct, axis=1).mean())
```

For my sample data, limited to years 2003, 2004 and 2005, the result is:

```
  Variable        2004        2005
0        A  925393.250  572893.250
1        B   54266.250   36841.250
2        C   18522.475   11722.475
3        D         NaN     325.000
4        E   26990.475   12840.475
5        F  874377.000  466827.000
```

Or use just the grouping, without joining with *Variable* column (and
convert to a *Numpy* array):

```
resNp = df2.groupby(grpDct, axis=1).mean().values
```

This time the result is:

```
array([[9.2539325e+05, 5.7289325e+05],
       [5.4266250e+04, 3.6841250e+04],
       [1.8522475e+04, 1.1722475e+04],
       [          nan, 3.2500000e+02],
       [2.6990475e+04, 1.2840475e+04],
       [8.7437700e+05, 4.6682700e+05]])
```

## Edit

I noticed that you want the result for each year as a "total" mean,
not a mean for each row (in each year).

To get such result, you can rely solely on *Numpy* functions:

```
# Separate the "wanted" columns
a1 = df.iloc[:, 2:].values
# Create a list of "sections" for each year
a2 = np.array_split(a1, a1.shape[1] // 4, axis=1)
# Compute mean for each "section"
resNp = np.array([np.nanmean(a) for a in a2])
```

For my sample data I got (means for 2004 and 2005):

```
array([379909.89      , 200233.99090909])
```

Comment: Hi Valdi, I have tried your code on my program and it resulted in DataError: No numeric types to aggregate for result  = df[['Variables']].join(df2.groupby(grpDct, axis=1).mean())       I have updated a link to the excel file which I have trying to process in the question to see if it helps in troubleshooting.

Comment: The source of your problem may be *na* strings representing *NaN* values. Note that *read_excel* does not recognize them by default as *NaN*, so each column containing such a string is probably of *object* type (run *df.info()* and check the output to confirm it). To read *na* strings as *NaN* pass *na_values='na'* to *read_excel*.

Comment: Read documentation concerning *read_excel*. It includes values interpreted as *NaN*, including e.g. **upper case** *NA*, but **lower case** *na* is **not** on this list.

Comment: Hi Valdi, thank you for your assistance in this! Really appreciate it a lot!